# Why is VS2013 telling me to use scanf_s?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm in a programming class at Texas Tech University and after putting up with Python last semester, I'm finally in the C++ class. While we were making a HelloWorld program in class today, me and a few others got Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 telling us to use scanf_s instead of scanf like the instructor was using in his program. Below is my code as it stands.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

int i,j;
float x,y;
scanf("input a number: %d %d %f %f", &i, &j, &x, &y);

printf("print numbers a : %d \n",i);
printf("print numbers a : %10.3d \n", i);
printf("print numbers a : %-10.3d", i);

fflush(stdin);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would rather say... don't use it, unless you are ok with not portable code: afaik, it's a microsoft think — I believe it's just a "safier" version of scanf... good intention, but...

Comment: The [`scanf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) is a Visual Studio extension that is supposed to have extra security enhancements. It is *not* portable beyond Visual Studio.

Comment: Avoid the issue, you're using C++, so use std::cin and std::cout. Boom.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The `_s` family of functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170) are "secure" variants of standard library functions provided by Microsoft. Many standard library functions are not considered safe since they either don't allow or don't require the user to guard against buffer overflows. The `_s` functions are alternatives that allow/require buffer overflow protection (usually this means they take an extra argument specifying the size of the buffer you're passing in, but in the case of `scanf_s()` it requires the format string to contain width specifiers for each `%c`, `%C`, `%s` or `%S` parameter).

You can disable these warnings by setting the `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS` define in your project settings. Or, if you choose, switch to the `_s` functions (but note that doing so will tie your code to the Microsoft runtime libraries [or to C11; see comments below], and make it nonportable).

Comment: Actually, they are not totally Microsoft-only; they're an optional part of the C11 standard.

Comment: @Angew Interesting. Are Microsoft's implementations 100% compatible with the C11 standard? They've been around longer...

Comment: I don't know, haven't really checked. I know there's one case where the standard swapped order of parameters compared to a MS function (can't remember which one, MSDN has an article about it), but I believe the general idea was for them to be the same.

Comment: `bsearch_s` and `qsort_s` have different parameter orderings.  I don't know of any other differences, but I haven't fully audited the sources.  Parameter ordering differences are historical accidents:  the Visual C++ implementation was the first implementation of these functions, before they were standardized. In some cases, the C committee standardized something other than existing practice (Why, I know not).  Visual C++ also does not implement the C11 constraint handler that these secure functions are supposed to use (instead, we have a similar concept called the _invalid parameter handler_)

Comment: Axccording to the linked Microsoft article, you need to set `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` . `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS` is only mentioned in the context of POSIX name deprecation!